# How to run cabal in CI correctly (so to prevent conflicts while actually no any conflicts)?

Tags: haskell, gitlab-ci, cabal

I try to build a project with `cabal` in Gitlab CI (on Windows runner). And I get this error:

```
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it.
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: aeson-default-0.9.1.2 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: aeson (dependency of aeson-default)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: aeson, aeson-default)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: aeson-default, aeson
```

I ran before it `cabal update` but it did not help. How to fix it?

Comment: Does heeding the warning on your first line of output help?

Comment: Do you know what version of cabal you're using? Do you use any caching? If the answers are: 3.10 and yes, you may be experiencing https://github.com/haskell/actions/issues/203 (even though you're using GitLab).

Comment: Also, do you have a link to the repo?

Comment: It's 3.10, yep. I tried to update it manually, to add update in CI script, to change location (cabal binary is correct, I checked it). Finally I fixed the problem when I restarted gitlab-runner within the system account (I tried to avoid it, it had own account).

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn good link, thanks, I think something like this happened. IMHO alternative is to use CABAL_DIR, but I am not sure

Comment: Right. As a workaround, people suggest to `mkdir ~/. cabal` before setting up anything Haskell-related.